# Correct input_shape for an LSTM in kerasR

Tags: r, keras, lstm

I see a lot of help for similar topics in python but I was using the R implementation and can't seem to replicate any of the suggested solutions.

I am attempting to setup an LSTM like so,

```
mod <- Sequential()

mod$add(LSTM(50, activation = 'relu', dropout = 0.25, input_shape = c(dim(X_train_scaled)[1], dim(X_train_scaled)[2]), return_sequences = TRUE))

mod$add(Dense(1))

keras_compile(mod,  loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')

keras_fit(mod, X_train_scaled, Y_train, batch_size = 72, epochs = 10, verbose = 1, validation_split = 0.1)
```

However, when I run the `keras_fit` I get the following error,

`Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_36_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2000, 44)`

The X_train is a numeric matrix with 2000 rows and 44 columns that represent 2000 timesteps and the values of 44 features at each timestep

The Y_train is a numeric vector of length 2000

I should add that when I attempt to use a 3 dimensional value for the `input_shape` so as to specify an input shape that follows the `(samples, timesteps, features)` structure,  I get an error like this when I add the LSTM layer to the model,

`Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_37: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue.  I'm trying to find a solution since yesterday... alas!

Comment: From [link](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks.html) you see notation like `input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]])`, which throws error attempt to get more than one value from get real index, but, `input_shape = c(NULL,dim(train_norm_arr)[-1])` works, and gives ndim=3 as Andres answered. HTH, thrashing around in LSTM myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your train matrix should be 3-dimensional `(samples, timesteps, features)`. Then you have to use 2nd and 3rd dimensions for `input_shape`:

```
input_shape = c(dim(X_train_scaled)[2], dim(X_train_scaled)[3])
```

Also, number of rows in your dataset is `samples`, not `timesteps`. You can read more about `samples`, `timesteps` and `features` [here](https://www.quora.com/What-do-samples-features-time-steps-mean-in-LSTM).